# Shiny Datatable Click ID not working

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

Back again.  Working on a project and I'm stuck.  My click isn't working.  I've tried every iteration and can't figure it out.  Basically I want to select multiple lines in a datatable via a click, at which point I'll do some more filtering.  The click I'm having issues with.  Here's my code...  Do you see anything I'm missing?  Thanks. 
    library(forecast)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(DT)

library(forecast)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(DT)

```
source("NEW.R", local = TRUE)

branch1 <- unique(distinctlineitems$BRANCH)


 ui <- navbarPage(
 theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
 title = "EXPENDITURES",
 tabPanel("TAB1",

       sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(
           checkboxGroupInput("branches",label = NULL,choices = branch1      ,selected = NULL),
           actionButton('selectallB','Select All'),
           textInput("words", "Search"),
           h5("Separate keywords with commas."),
           plotOutput("plot", width = "100%"),
           plotOutput("season", width = "100%")),



         # Show a plot of the generated distribution
         mainPanel(
           fluidRow(csvDownloadUI("dwnld", "DOWNLOAD"), style =       "padding:10px"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("table")

 server <- function(input, output, session) {
 branchfilter <- reactive({
 filt <- distinctlineitems[distinctlineitems$BRANCH %in% input$branches,]
 return(filt)
 })

graphids <- reactive({
if(length(input$table_rows_selected) < 1) return(NULL)
id <- input$table_rows_selected
x <- branchfilter()$REMARKS[id]
})
output$table <- renderDataTable({
  test <- DT::datatable(branchfilter(),
               filter = "top",
               rownames = FALSE,
               selection = "multiple")

})
```

Comment: What's your `ui`?

Comment: And more importantly, where is `wordreact()` defined?

Comment: Would you close this one out for me?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was able to answer my own question on this one.  Because I was trying to test it under a Reactive I was unable to see the output.  In order to test, I had to wrap in an observe statement.  So easy.  After the fact.  Thanks tobiaseli_te.

observe(print(graphids()))